# Allow arbitrary text after page URL

Tags: customization, pages, templates, redirect, htaccess

I'm trying to add a page that is able to display different information from a database based on the URL.

`http://example.com/page/` retrieves the page. I want `http://example.com/page/whatever-information/` to be mapped to the same page, without a redirect or 404.

I've tried adding the following to .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^page/.+$ /index.php?p=123`

This partially works (no 404 error), but causes a redirect to `/page/`, which is not intended.

Any pointers?

Comment: I'm assuming that `whatever-information` is a child page? If not, please edit your question to elaborate, but if so, how about this - rather than messing with rewrite rules, create a template for *page* (**page-$slug.php**) that will consistantly output what you want, and when the user navigates to `http://example.com/page/whatever-information/` (or similar) use the `template_include` filter to ensure they are shown the correct page template.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not advisable as `http://example.com/page/whatever-information/` is how Wordpress deals with child pages and .htaccess Rewrites is part of how Wordpress identifies what page is being requested and what queries to run.

You should probably pass the `whatever-information` as something called a POST variable, then have code that runs on `page` and parses these variables to fetch the correct information.

Comment: I realize it would be a bit of a hack, but using a custom template to implement my functionality (a listing of second-hand cars) seems like the most straight-forward way to go. The `whatever-information` needs to go into the URL because of SEO; e.g. `http://www.example.com/cars/mercedes-benz-1234`. Do you have any suggestions as for how to implement this differently?

Comment: If suitable mercedes-benz-1234 should be a child page of cars, then deal with throwing out the correct content on that child page.